# Is it possible to use virtual currency to purchase a monthly premium account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I wonder if our iOS app can follow this design:

The app will reward users with certain amount of virtual coins each time they made some achievements; at the same time they can buy coins through IAP.

With the coins(no mattered through rewards or IAP) users can upgrade to a monthly based premium account.

My thought is the virtual coins could be seen as consumable items, which users may use to exchange for the premium status for a period of time. Not sure if this is in conflict with Apple's policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for In App Purchase then you cannot use virtual coins. I would recommend that you contact Apple Support and get it clarified from them.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you set your own conversion rates. For instance you could have an in app subscription for 1000 coins which will cost $ 0.99 or € 0.89 or ... Have a look at this WWDC video about subscriptions https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=308